# Ошибка кодировки в python ahk

Tags: python, autohotkey

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from ahk import AHK

control = AHK()

while True:
    if control.key_state('CapsLock', mode='T'):
        control.send_input("Привет мир!{ENTER}")

    elif control.key_state('NumLock', mode='T'):
        break
```

Вывод: РџСЂРёРІРµС‚ РјРёСЂ

Ссылка на модуль: https://pypi.org/project/ahk/

Если запускать в обычном .ahk файле, то все работает

```
F6::
SendInput, Привет мир!{ENTER}
```

Вывод: Привет мир!

Answer (score 1):

Я уже нашел решение!

Оказывается проблема была в модуле ahk.

Надо было открыть файл script.py

```
"Корневая папка Python\Lib\site-packages\ahk\script.py"
```

и внести изменение в функцию _run_script

```
    def _run_script(self, script_text, **kwargs):
        blocking = kwargs.pop('blocking', True)
        runargs = [self.executable_path, '/ErrorStdOut', '*']
        decode = kwargs.pop('decode', False)
        script_bytes = bytes(script_text, 'utf-8')
        if blocking:
            result = subprocess.run(runargs, input=script_bytes,
                                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, **kwargs)
            if decode:
                logger.debug('Stdout: %s', repr(result.stdout))
                logger.debug('Stderr: %s', repr(result.stderr))
                return result.stdout.decode()
            else:
                return result
        else:
            proc = subprocess.Popen(runargs, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, **kwargs)
            try:
                proc.communicate(script_bytes, timeout=0)
            except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
                pass  # for now, this seems needed to avoid blocking and use stdin
            return proc
```

на

```
    def _run_script(self, script_text, **kwargs):
        blocking = kwargs.pop('blocking', True)
        runargs = [self.executable_path, '/ErrorStdOut', '*']
        decode = kwargs.pop('decode', False)
        script_bytes = bytes(script_text, 'cp1251')
        if blocking:
            result = subprocess.run(runargs, input=script_bytes,
                                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, **kwargs)
            if decode:
                logger.debug('Stdout: %s', repr(result.stdout))
                logger.debug('Stderr: %s', repr(result.stderr))
                return result.stdout.decode()
            else:
                return result
        else:
            proc = subprocess.Popen(runargs, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, **kwargs)
            try:
                proc.communicate(script_bytes, timeout=0)
            except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
                pass  # for now, this seems needed to avoid blocking and use stdin
            return proc
```

(заменить кодировку "utf-8" на "cp1251")

Answer (score 0):

Фиксить нужно не библиотеку, а ваш текст.

```
In [15]: text = "Привет мир!"

In [16]: cp = text.encode().decode("cp1251")
```

Вот ваша строка:

```
In [17]: cp
Out[17]: 'РџСЂРёРІРµС‚ РјРёСЂ!'
```

Чтобы вернуть ее в нормаьный вид, ее нужно правильно декодировать:

```
In [18]: cp.encode("cp1251").decode("utf8")
Out[18]: 'Привет мир!'
```